# NIntegrate gives the wrong result

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

I have tried to calculate an integral of a function numerically  using `NIntegrate`, but sadly it seems like I do not get the correct result from it.

The function $\phi(x,y)$ is defined using a function $A(c)$ which is given by an parametric numerical integral. The definition is

```
A[c_] := Evaluate[2 NIntegrate[(2 ArcCos[Sqrt[1 - c]/Sqrt[(c + Cos[π x]) Sec[(πx)/2]^2]])/π,
{x, -((2 ArcCos[Sqrt[1 - c]/Sqrt[1 + c]])/π), (2 ArcCos[Sqrt[1 - c]/Sqrt[1 + c]])/π}]]

r[x_, y_] := 1/Sqrt[π] Sqrt[A[1 - 2/(Cos[π/2 x]^-2 + Cos[π/2 y]^-2)]]

a = Sqrt[π]/2;
ϕ[x_, y_] := 2 ArcSin[1/Sqrt[2] a r[x/a, y/a]];
```

The function $\phi(x,y)$ defined in the triangle with corner points of $(0,0), (a,a), (a,-a)$ for $a=\frac{\pi}{2}$. By ploting the function $\phi(x,y)$ we can see it is pretty simillar to the function $\frac{\pi}{2a}x$:

```
Plot3D[{ϕ[x, y], π/(2 a) x}, {x, 0, a}, {y, -x, x}]
```

[image]

Therefore I expect the integral $$\intop_{0}^{a}\intop_{-x}^{x}\left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\right)^{2}dydx$$ to be close to $a^2\cdot(\frac{\pi}{2a})^2=\frac{\pi^2}{4}\approx2.467$.
But when I'm integrating numerically over $\left(\partial_{x}\phi\right)^{2}$ I get something very different:

```
In[69]:= NIntegrate[(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(x\)]\(ϕ[x, y]\)\))^2, {x, 0, a}, {y, -x, x}]

During evaluation of In[69]:= NIntegrate::nlim: x = Indeterminate is not a valid limit of integration.

During evaluation of In[69]:= General::ivar: Sqrt[π]/2 is not a valid variable.

During evaluation of In[69]:= NIntegrate::nlim: x = Indeterminate is not a valid limit of integration.

During evaluation of In[69]:= General::ivar: Sqrt[π]/2 is not a valid variable.

During evaluation of In[69]:= NIntegrate::nlim: x = Indeterminate is not a valid limit of integration.

During evaluation of In[69]:= General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::nlim will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[69]:= General::ivar: Sqrt[π]/2 is not a valid variable.

During evaluation of In[69]:= General::stop: Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[69]:= NIntegrate::write: Tag Times in (Sqrt[π] x)/2 is Protected.

During evaluation of In[69]:= NIntegrate::write: Tag Times in (Sqrt[π] x)/2 is Protected.

During evaluation of In[69]:= NIntegrate::write: Tag Times in (Sqrt[π] x)/2 is Protected.

During evaluation of In[69]:= General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::write will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[69]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

During evaluation of In[69]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 18 recursive bisections in x near {x,y} = {0.93974199467253037576508489792104228399693965911865234375000000000,0.713879}. NIntegrate obtained 0.605531 +0.0100204 I and 0.00006594026997516764` for the integral and error estimates.

Out[69]= 0.605531 + 0.0100204 I
```

I get many warnings which are probably due to the definition of $A(c)$, but in other cases I did this I got the correct results despite these warnings. In this case I get that the integral fail to converge, and indeed the result I get here is $0.605531$ (plus an imagenary contribution) is probablt too far from the approximately expected $2.467$.
I tried many integration methods using the `Methods` option, but non of them helped. Monte-Carlo methods also gave results of about $0.605$.

In addition I tried to calculate the integral by definin $A(c)$ using `A[c_?NumericQ]`. In this case the integral did not give results at all.

Does anyone know what the problem is? Am I wrong and the integral is so different from the one over $\frac{\pi}{2a}$ despite the similar apperence of the functions?

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like there's a `\[Pi]x` that should be `\[Pi]*x`, but that might be a copy-and-paste problem.  That's at least one possible coding issue, here. Also, I don't think you  you can take the derivative of a numerical function that's defined like `A[x_?NumericQ] := ...`

Comment: @march Thank you for mentioning, the $\pi$ is indeed just a copy-and-paste problem. It did not give a problem in the code.
About the ?NumericQ, you are right. I just tried both with and without the ?NumericQ to see if it changes the result, but it doesn't.

Comment: I am trying to run your code as we speak, but it's running for a long time. It hasn't kicked back any errors yet, though.  In any case, the point is that `A` is defined in terms of a numerical integral, and I don't think that `D` is equipped to handle that situation.

Comment: Thank you very much @march. It seems like I messed up, and another thing I wrote in the notebook interacted with the calculation for reason I'm not sure of.
The results I wrote are actually the results I get if I do _not_ use ?NumericQ. If I do, the integral just does not give any results, as you mentioned. I updated the question so it would be clear.

Answer (score 3):

You made an incorrect conclusion

> Therefore I expect the integral $$\intop_{0}^{a}\intop_{-x}^{x}\left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\right)^{2}dydx $$ to be close to
> $a^2\cdot(\frac{\pi}{2a})^2=\frac{\pi^2}{4}\approx2.467$

If  functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are close on some interval, the derivatives $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ are not necessary close there. In fact, in your case the code

```
A[c_] := Evaluate[ 2 NIntegrate[(2 ArcCos[
    Sqrt[1 - c]/
     Sqrt[(c +  Cos[\[Pi] x]) Sec[(\[Pi] x)/
          2]^2]])/\[Pi], {x, -((2 ArcCos[
       Sqrt[1 - c]/Sqrt[1 + c]])/\[Pi]), (2 ArcCos[
     Sqrt[1 - c]/Sqrt[1 + c]])/\[Pi]}]]

r[x_, y_] := 1/Sqrt[\[Pi]] Sqrt[A[1 - 2/(Cos[\[Pi]/2 x]^-2 + Cos[\[Pi]/2 y]^-2)]]

a = Sqrt[\[Pi]]/2;\[Phi][x_, y_] := 2 ArcSin[1/Sqrt[2] a r[x/a, y/a]];

Plot3D[{Evaluate[D[\[Phi][x, y], x]], \[Pi]/(2 a) }, {x, 0, a}, {y, -x, x}]
```

results in

[image]

As we see, the plots are not close.

Comment: Thank you @user64494, but I do not see how it makes sense. We can see from the plot of $\phi(x,y)$ that its derivative is around to the one of $\frac{\pi}{2a}x$. If we try ploting constant $y$ slices of $\phi(x,y)$, and then we can clearly see that its derivative is sometimes above and sometimes below the one $\frac{\pi}{2a}x$, but the function you ploted gives only smaller derivative. This is probably a numerical error.
Following @Bob Hanlon's, by taking the derivative using `ND` and ploting we get a different function, that has values around $\frac{\pi}{2a}$.

Comment: @Roy: I am out  of MMA now so I'll reply later.

Comment: @Roy: (i) In the Bob Hanlon's notations  `Plot3D[D[\[Phi][x, y], x], {x, 0, a}, {y, -x, x}]` produces an empty plot. (ii) The plots in ny answer and the Bob Hanlon's  numeric result `2.767` are in accordance.  The derivatives differ by $\approx 0.5$. This implies the integrals differ by $\approx 0.5\cdot 1\cdot 1 /2=0.25$.

Comment: But as Bob Hanlon specified, using `ND` instead of `D` does give a plot. Also taking the numerical derivative by finite differences gives a plot similar to the one `ND` gives.
If the derivatives differ by $\approx0.5$, than the why would the integrals differ by about $0.25$? Did you mean to multiply by the area of the triangle? The area is $1/2\cdot a \cdot 2a=a^2$, and the integrals should differ by $~0.5a^2\approx0.4$.
In addition, in the plot you showed the derivative is **smaller** than $\pi/2a$, but Bob Hanlon's result is **larger** than the one given from $\pi/2a$.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The argument of a function which uses a numeric technique should be restricted to numeric values. However, do not put `Evaluate` on the RHS of the definition. The `Evaluate` will try to evaluate immediately before there is a numeric value for the argument.

```
A[cv_?NumericQ] := Module[
  {c = SetPrecision[cv, Max[15, Precision[cv]]]},
  2 NIntegrate[(2 ArcCos[Sqrt[1 - c]/
         Sqrt[(c + Cos[π x]) Sec[(π x)/2]^2]])/π,
    {x, -((2 ArcCos[Sqrt[1 - c]/Sqrt[1 + c]])/π),
     (2 ArcCos[Sqrt[1 - c]/Sqrt[1 + c]])/π},
    WorkingPrecision -> Max[15, Precision[cv]]]]

r[x_, y_] := 1/Sqrt[π] *
  Sqrt[A[1 - 2/(Cos[π/2 x]^-2 + Cos[π/2 y]^-2)]]

a = Sqrt[π]/2;

ϕ[x_, y_] := 2 ArcSin[1/Sqrt[2] a r[x/a, y/a]];
```

To take the derivative of a numeric function you will need to use a numeric technique, i.e., [`ND`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/NumericalCalculus/ref/ND.html)

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

NIntegrate[
 (ND[ϕ[x, y], x, x0, WorkingPrecision -> 12])^2, 
 {x0, 0, a}, {y, -x0, x0},
 AccuracyGoal -> 10,
 WorkingPrecision -> 12]

(* 2.76682450023 *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bob Hanlon! This seems to be the solution.
I still wonder what exactly Mathematica is doing when I'm asking for a derivative using "regular" derivative commands that gives such wrong results.

Comment: I checked it more, and something is still different from what I expect. I tried to calculate the numeriacal derivative by myself using finite differences by
`d\[Phi][x_, y_] := (\[Phi][x + h, y] - \[Phi][x - h, y])/(2 h)` for small $h$ (`h = 0.00000001` for example).
Integrating over the square of this function gives a different result of 2.3798, which is about 0.4 less. Changing the `AccuracyGoal` and `WorkingPrecision` does not change this result significantly.
The `ND` function is probably more accurate, but with such differences I'm not sure I can trust the results I get...